# friction not working correctly in my 2d game - unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 2d game in unity, and I am trying to add friction to slow the player down when he is on the ground. I launch the player into the air with the rigidbody's add force. I have heard of physics materials, and am currently trying to use them. I am using the 2d version of them, I made one material which had high friction. I add the material to the floor, and then I play the game, and my character is still sliding on the floor. I thought the problem might be with the player not having a physics material, so I added one. It still didn't work.

- I tried doing different combinations with the different materials.
- I tried attaching a rigidbody, but kinematic to the floor.
- I tried looking it up, and couldn't find an answer.

Here is the code that moves the player:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isGrounded = true;
    public float fireForce;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        camera = camObj.GetComponent<Camera>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        RotateToPoint();
        Fire();
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D obj)
    {
        if (obj.gameObject.tag == "surface")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D obj)
    {
        if (obj.gameObject.tag == "surface")
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
    void Fire()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * fireForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know if I am approaching the problem correctly. If I am not, does anyone know how to avoid slippery game objects. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a higher angular drag was the solution to my problem. Angular drag is what slows the object down along its rotation. Friction may not always be the problem.
[image: Rigidbody2D component values]

Notice the two highlighted variables. You might want to raise these values (I changed angular drag from its default) to something higher. Adding the physics material might help, you should try this if this first solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not limiting the velocity of the player, so what you can do is set an if statement if the player is touching the floor and the velocity is higher than what you want it to be.

Example:

```cs
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isGrounded == true && rb.velocity.x > 1 || isGrounded == true && rb.velocity.z >1)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I found the problem.